# get array of roles ID of a User in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

This is **User** model:

```
class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The roles that belong to the user.
     */
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
    }
}
```

And this is **Role** Model:

```
class Role extends Model
{
    /**
     * The users that belong to the role.
     */
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

As you can see these two models have Many to Many relationship between them.

Now I want to get an array of **ID's** of roles of a user. For that I wrote this :

```
$user = User::find($id);
return $user->roles()->get(['roles.role_id']);
```

But above code returns an array containing objects refering to each role ID that user have:

```
[
    {
        "role_id": 9,
        "pivot": {
            "user_id": 2,
            "role_id": 9
        }
    },
    {
        "role_id": 14,
        "pivot": {
            "user_id": 2,
            "role_id": 14
        }
    }
]
```

But I want to return an array of ID's of roles like this:

```
[9,14,......]
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: could be loop over the object to get only `role_id`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `lists()` Eloquent function is helpful for this. Note that it returns a collection, not an array, so if you must have the array you'll need `toArray` as well.

```
$roles = $user
  ->roles()
  ->lists('roles.role.id')
  ->toArray();
```

**UPDATE**: (For versions >= 5.2)

The lists() method was ***deprecated*** in the laravel versions >= 5.2, use pluck() method instead:

```
$roles = $user
  ->roles
  ->pluck('id')
  ->toArray();
```

If you need a **string**, for example in a **blade**, you can use without **toArray()** attachment:

```
$roles = $user
  ->roles
  ->pluck('id');
```